# Facebook webhook for pages not sending info to server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to integrate facebook with my application.

I set up a server, webhook subscription went well (subscribed to fields: feed, conversation and messages), callback url is fine, test messages from app dashboard are coming to my server.

Then I have added my fb page to my fb app via graph api explorer and want to test creating posts. I created a post in two ways: via graph api explorer and via fb page. Anyway, no info is coming to my server.

I tested it while app is in development mode and in live mode.

What is wrong with my thinking? Any and all information will be appreciated.

=================================================================

CLOSING

My bad. I didn't noticed that facebook needs to review my app in order to start working

Comment: Did you choose your own app id correctly in GAE? When you read the apps subscribed to your page back via API, is your app among it?

Comment: Yes. When i'm reading my subscribed apps using page_id (of course) in return i get my app id (only in development mode)